# Sed remove everything between first and second instance of a character?

Tags: string, bash, replace, sed

I'm not very experienced with sed, but If I have a string like this:

```
asdf | this is something | something else | nothing | qwerty
```

can I remove everything between the first and second instances of `|`, plus one of them?

The ideal output would be:

```
asdf | something else | nothing | qwerty
```

I tried `sed 's/|*|//2'`, but this only removes the second pipe.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this:

```
sed 's/|[^|]*//'
```

with your example

```
kent$ sed 's/|[^|]*//' <<<"asdf | this is something | something else | nothing | qwerty"                                                                      
asdf | something else | nothing | qwerty
```

Answer (score 2):

`s/|[^|]*|/|/` should do the job

```
echo 'asdf | this is something | something else | nothing | qwerty' | 
sed 's/|[^|]*|/|/'
asdf | something else | nothing | qwerty
```

Answer (score 2):

**Can be done using awk also:**

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '{sub($2 " *\\|", "")}1' <<< "$str"
asdf | something else | nothing | qwerty
```

**Using pure BASH:**

```
echo "${str%%|*}|${str#*|*|}"
asdf | something else | nothing | qwerty
```